# Play local audio wav file with react-app from docker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker-compose, react-player

I'm trying to use [react-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player) to play local wav files.

I'm not sure of the following.
Does the player support **wav** files?
When I'm running the react-app through docker what should I put in the url prop?

Docker-compose volume setup

```
volumes:
  - /Users/user/app/sounds:/app/audioExport
```

My app is running on http://localhost:3000

I tried the following

```
var path = "http://localhost:3000/app/audioExport/sound.wav"
var path = "/app/audioExport/sound.wav"
var path = "/Users/user/app/sounds/sound.wav"
```

I tried the static method  `ReactPlayer.canPlay(path)`

I get `Invalid URI. Load of media resource  failed.`.

In the console I get an empty src prop

`<audio src="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" preload="auto" controls=""crossorigin="true"></audio>`

Here is the component

```
<ReactPlayer 
          className='react-player fixed-bottom'
          controls = {true}
          width='100%'
          height='100%'
          type="audio/wav"
          forceAudio = {true}
          config={{
            file: {
              attributes: {
                crossOrigin: "true",
              }
            }
          }}
          url={path}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

For people who might stumble upon the question. I learned that one cannot play local files from React App without importing the sounds in the app. This is for security reasons and I was able to find that out because hosted sounds played fine but local files gave an error. This led me to create an API endpoint which streams the wav file to the React app.